# $f(x)$ is an odd function on $[\frac{-T}{2},\frac{T}{2}]$ and has a period $T$. Prove that $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is periodic with period $T$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $f(x)$ is an odd function on $[\frac{-T}{2},\frac{T}{2}]$ and has a period $T$. Prove that $\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is periodic with period $T$.

The problem boils down to proving $\int_x^{x+T} f(z)dz = 0$. We can reduce this further to $\int_0^T f(z)dz$. This is where I am stuck. Any hint?

Comment: Hint: it's odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may observe that, by the [fondamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements),
$$
\left(\int_x^{x+T} f(z)dz\right)_x'=f(x+T)-f(x)=0 \tag1
$$ giving
$$
\int_x^{x+T} f(z)dz=C \,\, \text{(constant)} \tag2
$$ then, putting $x=-\dfrac{T}2$ in $(2)$ **using that $f$ is odd on**$[-\dfrac{T}2,\dfrac{T}2]$ gives $C=0$.

Comment: @@Olivier Oloa) How you can say that $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x+T}f(z)\,dz$ exists ?

Comment: You can give a proof of $\int_x^{x+T} f(z)dz=0$  in two steps. We start with piecewise continuous functions on $[a,b]$ (giving the existence of the above derivative). Then, by density,  we extend the result concerning $f$ in $L^1([a,b])$.